# Prolog printing all solutions and wanting to get yes/no output

Tags: prolog

I just started learning Prolog and my task is to write a predicate poklapanje(M,V) which returns yes if all the elements of list M are the first elements of list V, for example poklapanje([1,2],[1,2,3]) should return yes. The first question I have is what is the difference between true and yes, because I am getting true in my solution? Second, when I type poklapanje(X,[1,2,3]) I should get:

```
X = [];
X = [1];
X = [1,2];
X = [1,2,3];
no
```

and I get:

```
X = [];
false
```

Why? I guess it has something to do with my implementation and printing true/false instead of yes/no.

Here is my code:

```
poklapanje([],[_|_]).
poklapanje([A|B],[C|D]):- A == C, poklapanje(B,D).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot add a comment (not enough reputation), i'm putting this here. I'll try to explain why your code doesn't work and why Fabricator's code works.

First problem you have, is

```
A == C
```

which is not doing what you wanted to achieve. Instead, you want to unify variables, so use

```
A = C
```

or even better, as suggested in the correct answer

```
poklapanje([A|B],[A|D])
```

If you do it with A == C, in the second step you would have 1 == C, and this will fail as C is not equal to 1.

Second issue, which is already explained, is

```
poklapanje([],[_|_]).
```

which will fail in the last step, where D is an empty list. Empty list doesn't have any members, so it will not unify with [ _ | _ ]. You might be tempted to use [ _ ] to fix this problem, but that would unify only with the list which has one member. That's why you have to use _, which will unify with any list:

```
poklapanje([], _).
```

Hope it clears it up for you a bit. :-)

Comment: Thank you! The A = C thing was the problem, have no idea how I missed that one and didn't try with one =. Thanks again. Everything is clear, also the thing about base case.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between `yes` and `true`. It's just difference between Prolog implementations. For example, we get `true` in SWI-Prolog, and `yes` in GNU Prolog.

I'm not sure how you posed your query. Here's the output from running your code:

```
?- poklapanje(X,[1,2,3]).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

It's missing `[1, 2, 3]` because `poklapanje([],[_|_]).` fails for `poklapanje([],[]).`

I would implement it like this:

```
poklapanje([], _).
poklapanje([A|B],[A|D]) :- poklapanje(B,D).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, when I run my code, I get exactly what I wrote, and not what you copied, and what should be the output. I am really confused. I use SWI-Prolog, the latest stable version on Win 7.

Ps. I also tried it in online emulator and I get the same as in my case! Am I missing something? When I test it, my command is poklapanje(X,[1,2,3]). with the dot in the end. Then it prints one output and waits. Then I hit ; and it stops and says false.

Comment: You you obtain the follow result:

X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.

and finally return false, it's because there are no more solutions. But the result is right.

Comment: Despite their identical informal meaning, there is one very important difference between `yes` and `true`: You can *copy and paste* the answer `true` on the toplevel, and again obtain `true`. You *cannot* do that with `yes`, because `yes/0` is not a built-in predicate. Thus, the SWI toplevel can be seen as partially evaluating the original query, yiedling a declaratively equivalent version that can be used instead by just copying and pasting the answer! That's a very nice declarative property. You put goals in, you get equivalent goals out.

Comment: @mat, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know about the `true/0` built-in predicate